# Where does "this.state" comes from when using TypeScript in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was wondering where does the property `this.state` comes from when using React with TypeScript?

```
public constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
        userName:"Code to html, one way -->",
        password:""
    };
}
```

We are not importing it in the super() call, so where does it comes from?

Comment: It has nothing to do with typescript - just plain old JS classes... When you extend Component you inherit a few methods like `render` `setState` etc...

Comment: Yes, but this.state is not a method...

Comment: Look into how JS classes work... the key word this should be your clue... see @Dennis answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from the internal implementation of React component which you inherit by extending the class `React.Component`:

```
class MyComponent from React.Component {
   // this.setState, this.state,
   // lifecycle methods and more 
}
```

See [`React.Component`](http://React.Component) and its [**instance properties**](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#instance-properties).

Comment: So basically we are getting this.state automatically by extending class Component?

Comment: Yes, you also get component's lifecycle methods etc. See attached link

Comment: @BenAshkenazi you should accept answers which were helpful to you (I see you haven't accepted any question you asked, there are good answer that people put much effort to them)

Answer (score 0):

> where does it comes from?

It comes from the constructor. The line you are asking about is exactly where `this.state` is initialized.

Comment: But how does it comes from the constructor if we are not calling it specifically from the Component class?

Comment: @BenAshkenazi "if we are not calling it" Calling what?